# Refer to next element of list when iterating using Map

Tags: list-manipulation

Is it possible to refer to the next element of the list when I'm using `Map` or should I always use `For` in this case?
For example I can write:

```
(1 + #1) & /@ {a, b, c, d}
```

but I can not write:

```
(1 + #1 + #2) & /@ {a, b, c, d}
```

The problem with the last element should be also avoided. So in last example I would like to get something like

```
{ 1 + a + b, 1 + b + c, 1 + c + d, 1 + d}
```

Comment: It is possible if you use `MapIndexed`. Also, `#2` refers to the second _argument_ of a function, not the second element of a list (or the next).

Comment: I tend to use `Partition` in these situations, like `(1 + #1 + #2) & @@@ Partition[{a, b, c, d}, 2, 1]` or `MapThread[(1 + #1 + #2) &, Transpose@Partition[{a, b, c, d}, 2, 1]]`. I hope somebody will show a smarter way here...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One can use `MapIndexed` to access the next (or previous or any arbitrary offset) element of the currently mapped element. However, you also need to make checks so that you don't index it beyond its bounds. For example:

```
With[{list = Range@5}, MapIndexed[{f@#, f@list[[Mod[#2[[1]] + 1, Length@list, 1]]]} &, list]]
(* {{f[1], f[2]}, {f[2], f[3]}, {f[3], f[4]}, {f[4], f[5]}, {f[5], f[1]}} *)
```

Here, I've chosen to wrap the index back to the first element, but you can choose something else.

As Pinguin Dirk mentioned, `Partition` is also an option if your offsets are regular:

```
With[{list = Range@5}, {f@#, f@#2} & @@@ Partition[list, 2, 1, {1, 1}]]
```

Use the higher arguments of `Partition` to control how the endpoints/padding should be done.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this is as follows:

```
Map[Total[#] &, Partition[{a, b, c, d}, 2, 1]] + 1
```

the result is

```
(* {1 + a + b, 1 + b + c, 1 + c + d}   *)
```

Alternatively it can be written down in the pure function notations:

```
(1 + (#[[1]] + #[[2]]) &) /@ Partition[{a, b, c, d}, 2, 1]
```

The result is the same.

Comment: Or `1 + #1 + #2 & @@@ Partition[{a, b, c, d}, 2, 1]`

Comment: @ChrisDegnen: pretty much my comment above :)

Comment: @Pinguin Dirk Yes, it is the same as in your comment. I apologize to have skipped reading the comments and turned to answer at the spot.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch: no problem at all! I am glad I wasn't the only one with that idea (see the last sentence in my comment) :) all good!

Answer (score 4):

To achieve the result: {1+a+b,1+b+c,1+c+d,1+d} [noting `(1 + (#[[1]] + #[[2]]) &) /@ Partition[{a, b, c, d}, 2, 1]` -> {1 + a + b, 1 + b + c, 1 + c + d}] you could simply do:

```
list={a,b,c,d};
1+list+PadRight[Rest@list,4]
```

and adapt for arbitrary list

Comment: Alternatively `1 + list + PadLeft[list, 4, 0, 1]`

Answer (score 3):

Use `Partition` to produce `{{a, b}, {b, c}, {c, d}, {d}}` then for the operation in your example total the sublists at the second level and `+ 1`:

```
1 + Total[Partition[{a, b, c, d}, 2, 1, {1, 1}, {}], {2}]
```

Note the partitioning here differs from the other comments and answers which aren't delivering the answer you requested `{1+a+b,1+b+c,1+c+d,1+d}` as far as I can tell.

More generally you would do:

```
f @@@ Partition[{a, b, c, d}, 2, 1, {1, 1}, {}]
```

In your example `f` would be `(1 + #1 + ##2) &`

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to use `NestList` and carry the current index so you can manipulate it or control it.

```
list = {a, b, c, d} ;
f[x_, y_] = 1 + x + y ;

NestList[
 {#[[1]]+1, f[list[[#[[1]]+1]], If[#[[1]]+1+1 <= Length[list], list[[#[[1]]+1+1]], 0]]} &,    
   {1, f[list[[1]], list[[2]]]}, Length[list]-1][[All,2]]
```